# Having trouble with react-router and useLocation()

Tags: reactjs

I'm working in a React project and it uses another internal react project for reuseable contexts that is included as an npm package.

When trying to navigate to one of the main pages I hit an error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
at useLocation (other-react-project.js?v=aae38d29:3565:29)
at ContextProvider2 (other-react-project.js?v=aae38d29:4407:22)

function useLocation() {
      if (true) {
        !(typeof useContext === "function") ? true ? invariant(false, "You must use React >= 16.8 in order to use useLocation()") : invariant(false) : void 0;
      }
      return useContext(context).location //error on location here;
}
```

I've tried everything I could find like moving the browser router into ReactDOM.render like so

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter
```

Still can't seem to find what's wrong.

This application was working fine before, the changes being made are switching to vite from create-react-app.

Comment: my friend, this can't be answered without a proper context, at least track down the bug yourself and see what can cause the problem? have you tried to make a minimum reproducible example? What does *and it uses another internal react project for reuseable contexts that is included as an npm package* mean?  is it part of the problem?